# How to best filter gridview based on multiple databound dropdownlists in VB ASP.net & SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview which currently pulls in all records from a table. Additionally i have 4 dropdownlists that are databound to all possible values for each of the 4 columns and the dropdownlists lists are set as controls in the gridview for the database query.

On each downdownlist i have appended a blank value to the top which is the default value and anytime this value is chosen, the database uses this to return all results (no filter on that column when null).

This is the current database query.

```
SELECT 
    Week_Ending, Employee, Project, Status_Of_Employment 
FROM 
    Times  
WHERE 
    (@Project IS NULL OR Project LIKE @Project)
    AND (@Employee IS NULL OR Employee LIKE @Employee)
    AND (@Status_Of_Employment IS NULL OR Status_Of_Employment LIKE @Status_Of_Employment)
    AND (@WeekEnding IS NULL OR Week_Ending = CONVERT(datetime, @WeekEnding, 103))
```

This query allows the user to filter by any one or combination of the 4 columns

This solution is working really well except for the issue that on the initial page load, as all 4 dropdownlists are set to the empty value it returns all results from the database, which takes a very long time due to the amount of data.

What i would like to be able to do is to prevent the gridview from showing any results on the initial page load, until one of the filters is applied. I know that instead of Blank value being default i could use some invalid data such as "Please select a filter" for each dropdownlist, but ideally i would like the user not to have to pick the blank option in each dropdownlist to select no filter, as a majority of queries are usually just a single filter or two.

Is there a simple way to stop the query before the initial page load, or a best practice for filtering with the dropdownlists that i am overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: You might be loading `GridView` in `Page_Load` event, remove it.

Comment: It is not being loaded in the Page_Load event. But being a gridview with a configured datasource that has a query with valid control parameters, it will automatically show results matching the query.

Comment: Change it to load from code. Then you can have control over when to load.

Comment: Move your sqldatasource to code behind, and don't bind your gridview on first load

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have changed this to code behind. Solution posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of programmatically moving the gridview bind to the datasource into the code behind, i have instead removed the SelectCommand from the datasource and added it programmatically on the first postback. That way my gridview still loads and displays my EmptyDataText value.

```
Dim dataSourceBindComplete As Boolean = False

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then
        If dataSourceBindComplete = False Then
            dataSourceBindComplete.SelectCommand = "SELECT Week_Ending, Employee, Project, Status_Of_Employment FROM Times WHERE (@Project IS NULL OR Project LIKE @Project) AND (@Employee IS NULL OR Employee LIKE @Employee) AND (@Status_Of_Employment IS NULL OR Status_Of_Employment LIKE @Status_Of_Employment) AND (@WeekEnding IS NULL OR Week_Ending = CONVERT(datetime, @WeekEnding, 103))"
            dataSourceBindComplete = True
        End If         
    End If
End Sub
```